# cannot start cassandra: +HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, cassandra

I'm trying to start cassandra (installed with chef) and always getting this error

```
xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms245M -Xmx245M -Xmn61M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k
```

I have tried with Xss180k, Xss256k and Xss160k.

Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: That doesn't look like an error message.

Comment: the end of message: -Xms245M -Xmx245M -Xmn61M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not an error message, that's a JVM option to dump the heap when an out of memory error occurs.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbzrr